# Return new table with values where rows are modified between 2 versions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure

```
Table1 
ID  SpecificName  Value  Modified
3   Drogon        73     0
4   Viserion      44     0 
5   Rhaegal       70     0

Table2 
ID  SpecificName  Value  Modified
8   Drogon        87     0
9   Viserion      20     0 
10   Rhaegal       70     0
```

I would like to modify the Modified column values where `Table1.SpecificName == Table2.SpecificName AND Table1.Value != Table2.Value` and return something like:

```
Table3 
   SpecificName  Value  Modified
   Drogon        87     1
   Viserion      20     1 
   Rhaegal       70     0
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.SpecificName,
       t2.Value,
       case when t1.Value != t2.Value then 1 else 0 end as Modified
from t1 left join t2 on t1.SpecificName  = t2.SpecificName
```

We join both table (left join is used to process missing values as well).

We introduce a Modified column with value based on comparing original and joined table. If the values are the same Modified is 0.

Comment: Thank you. It looks right when reading it. I will check and accept it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired result, you can use `CASE`

```
select t2.SpecificName, t2.value,
case when (t1.value <> t2.value) then 1
     when (t1.value = t2.value) then 0
     ELSE NULL
end
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.SpecificName = t2.SpecificName;
```

Inner join is used in assumption that only matching values are required.
Below is the result generated as required using the above query.

[image]

You can check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/TYY45121)

Comment: No need additionally check names in the CASE/WHEN. Inner join could be not enough if t2 does not have the value.

Comment: @stanislavL, inner join wasa used on assumption that result is required for matching names only. adding NAME is case was my bad :-)